# Show and Hide a Custom Cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, hide, show

My UITableView has one section, and if all cells are visible there will be a total of 6.

There is only one cell that I would like to be able to show and hide.

Here's an overview:

cell 0 - always shown

cell 1 - always shown

cell 2- always shown

cell 3 - always shown

cell 4 - initially hidden / will show or hide if cell 3 is tapped

cell 5 - always shown

Here's a sample of what I have tried for animating/showing the cell through didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Not sure if I am on the right track, but if someone could take a look and help me see where I have messed up I would greatly appreciate it!

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if (indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        if (self.indexPathSelected != indexPath)
        {
            [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.indexPathSelected.row+1 inSection:self.indexPathSelected.section]].hidden = YES;

            [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

            [tableView beginUpdates];

            [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section]] performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:NO afterDelay:0.25];

            self.indexPathSelected = indexPath;

            [tableView endUpdates];

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

So when I tap on cell 3, it just makes the last cell flicker.

Comment: be careful if (self.indexPathSelected != indexPath) is a pointer comparaison and not the value of section and row.

Answer (score 0):

By considering, there will be of total 6 rows in tableview and only one section, for this better u make a mutable array to hold all the objects for ur tableview then use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:` instead of using selector following code gives the example how to hide and show the tableview cell

```
 mutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"cell 1",@"cell 2",@"cell 3",@"cell 4",@"cell 6", nil]; //initially ur array contains only 5 objects notice that "cell 5" is not  there this will be hidden

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {   
     return 1; 
  }

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {

     return [mutArray count];
  }

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   UITableViewCell *cell = [self.aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
   if(mutArray.count != 6) //initially only 5 rows are present
   {
      if(cell == nil)
       {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

       }

    cell.textLabel.text = [mutArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
 }
  else //for 5th row it must be a custom cell
   {
     return [mutArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//becz u are already initilised ur custom cell just return it
  }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if(indexPath.row == 3)
  {
      int totalRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];

      [tableView beginUpdates];
      if(totalRows == 5)
       {
        //initilise ur custom cell and add it to datasource array
        CustomCell *customCell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"customCell"];
        customCell.textLabel.text = @"cell 5";
        [mutArray insertObject:customCell atIndex:4];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

      }
    else
      {
        [mutArray removeObjectAtIndex:5];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
     }
    [tableView endUpdates];
 }
}
```

if all ur cells are custom then dont need to comepare in `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method

Hope this helps u :)